# No Mapping for GET even though mapping is right

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

> > 2019-09-05 14:02:28.776  WARN 11096 --- [nio-8080-exec-3]
> >     o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET
> >     /company/delete

I have a CRUD project using spring boot & JSP pages.

this is the controller delete method

```
@PostMapping("delete/{coupid}")
    public String removeCoupon(@PathVariable int coupid) {

        couponService.deleteById(coupid);

        return "couponRemoved";
    }
```

there is a method that shows all the coupons in a JSP page:

```
@GetMapping("/read")
public String getAllCoupons(Model theModel) {

    List<Coupon> theCoupon = companyService.getCurrentCompany().getCoupons();

    theModel.addAttribute("theCoupon", theCoupon);

    return "showAllCoupons";
}
```

simply adding each coupon to the model & then redirecting to a page that shows all the coupons with a loop:

```
<table class="i">
    <tr>
               <th>id</th>
               <th>title</th>
               <th>start</th>
               <th>end</th>
               <th>amount</th>
               <th>type</th>
               <th>message</th>
               <th>price</th>
               <th>image</th>
           </tr>

<c:forEach var="tempCoupon" items="${theCoupon}" >
<tr> 
<td> ${tempCoupon.coupid} </td>
<td> ${tempCoupon.title} </td>
<td> ${tempCoupon.startd} </td>
<td> ${tempCoupon.endd} </td>
<td> ${tempCoupon.amount} </td>
<td> ${tempCoupon.type} </td>
<td> ${tempCoupon.message} </td>
<td> ${tempCoupon.price} </td>
<td> ${tempCoupon.image} </td>
<td><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/company/delete?coupid=${tempCoupon.coupid}"> Remove ${tempCoupon.coupid} </a></td>

</tr>
</c:forEach>

</table>
```

As you can see inside that JSP c:forEach loop I also included a href link:

```
<td><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/company/delete?coupid=${tempCoupon.coupid}"> Remove ${tempCoupon.coupid} </a></td>
```

it takes the current coupon in the loop and puts its id into the link.

when I run it and click on REMOVE I get this :

> 2019-09-05 14:02:28.776  WARN 11096 --- [nio-8080-exec-3]
>   o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET
>   /company/delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your request you are using `coupid` as `PathVariable` not as a `RequestParam` so send it like it as well

e.g:

```
<td><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/company/delete/${tempCoupon.coupid}"> Remove ${tempCoupon.coupid} </a></td>
```

So basically your resource can be accessed like `/company/delete/123` and you are trying to access it like: `/company/delete?coupid=123` which causes the error.

**Also** you are actually sending a `GET` request but your resource is a `POST` so change it to `GET` as:

```
@GetMapping("delete/{coupid}")
public String removeCoupon(@PathVariable int coupid) {

     couponService.deleteById(coupid);

     return "couponRemoved";
}
```

Comment: And I want to add that this is dangerous... One google index and your content is gone...

Comment: what do you mean by that? in the url?